# Select from Multiple Columns - R

Tags: r

I have two sets of dataframes. One is combinations of strings where there are two columns, with different types of food:

```
#df.combination

      [,1]     [,2] 
[1,] "Apple" "Orange"         
[2,] "Apple" "Pear"         
[3,] "Apple" "Avocado" 
[4,] "Orange" "Pear"   
[5,] "Orange" "Avocado"
[6,] "Pear" "Avocado"
```

The other is a big "main" dataframe that has three columns of food ("id" "date" "food1" "food2" "food3") containing some of these combinations:

```
#df.main

      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]    
[1,] "1234"   "3/29"    "Sala"    "Pear"   "Avocado"
[2,] "1235"   "3/30"    "Apple"   "Pear"   "Meat"     
[3,] "1236"   "4/1"     "Orange"   "Juice"  "Apple" 
[4,] "1237"   "4/2"     "Pear"    "Avocado""Turkey"
```

If I wanted to write a script that searches **df.main** and selects rows containing all elements from **df.combination[1,]**, (so "Apple" and "Orange"), how would I be able to do that? The foods do not have to be in any order. The row just needs to contain the food. (i.e. **df.main[3,]**).

Here is an example output I would like to see. If I search for "Orange" and "Apple" (so **df.combination[1,]**) in **df.main**, I would like to see the id of row **df.main[2,]**

```
#search df.main for row containing df.combination[1,]
#output:
#1236
```

Thank you! Any help really appreciated.

Comment: You are mistaken. You don't have data.frames. Those are matrices.

Comment: Based on the first row of `df.combination`, the 3rd row in `df.main` matches.  I guess this should be done for all the rows in `df.combination`.   Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Hi @akrun, I edited the original post. Does this make sense? I apologize for not being very good at explaining things.

Comment: @Roland I just typed out the brackets (and changed the data to something as silly as food), so it's easier for people to see the data on Stack. It's not terribly important for the context of this problem. Thanks for the input tho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
 f1 <- function(dat1, dat2, rowindex){
  Indx <- apply(dat1[,grep('food', colnames(dat1))], 1,
         function(x) all(unlist(dat2[rowindex,]) %in% x))
  dat1[Indx,1]
 }
 f1(df.main, df.combination,1)
 #[1] 1236
 f1(df.main, df.combination,2)
 #[1] 1235
 f1(df.main, df.combination,3)
 #integer(0)
```

#### data

```
df.main <- structure(list(id = 1234:1237, date = c("3/29", "3/30",
"4/1", 
"4/2"), food1 = c("Sala", "Apple", "Orange", "Pear"), 
food2 = c("Pear", 
"Pear", "Juice", "Avocado"), food3 = c("Avocado", "Meat", "Apple", 
 "Turkey")), .Names = c("id", "date", "food1", "food2", 
 "food3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df.combination <- structure(list(V1 = c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", 
"Orange", "Orange", 
"Pear"), V2 = c("Orange", "Pear", "Avocado", "Pear", "Avocado", 
"Avocado")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! how does the second line of apply()  "...function(x) all(unlist(dat2[rowindex,]) %in% x" work?

Comment: @user1769069 By using `MARGIN=1` for the `apply`, we are looping through the rows of the 'main dataset' (subset with only 'food' columns).  When we specify the `rowindex` as 1, we get the first row of `df.combination`, which is still a data.frame, make it a vector with `unlist` and check whether the elements in that vector is present in `x` ie. the row of maindataset.  We use `all` to check if all the elements are present.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can write a function that extends the match function to filter on records that contain all the values of a certain vector, as follows:

```
match_filter <- function(df, match_to) { 
    apply(df, 
          1, 
          function(row) {
              !any(is.na(match(match_to, row)))
          })
}
```

So, the function `match_filter` takes 2 arguments: The first is `df`, which in this case would be your `df.main` dataset (or a subset of it - as we shall see). The second is `match_to`, which is the vector we want to match to, or we want to have all of its values in each record in `df`.

The function is easy to understand, however, it's useful to look at some of its components. What the `match` function is doing in this case is for each value in the `match_to` vector, return its index in the `row` vector (which is a row in `df`). If that value isn't found in `row`, then it returns `NA`. This is an example of running match on the second row of the dataset you provided:

```
> match(df.combination[1,], df.main[2,])
[1]  3 NA
```

Now, in order for the record `row` to satisfy what we want in this case, then the vector returned by the `match` function shouldn't have any `NA` values. That's why we wrapping the `match(match_to, row)` function with `!any(is.na())`. So, if there are any `NA`s in the return value of `match`, then we want to discard that record.

The reason we are wrapping all of this in an `apply` function is because we want to run the internal function (`function(row){...}`) on each row of `df` and that's what the `apply` functions are used for.

This is an example of using the function defined above on your dataset:

```
> df.main[ match_filter(df.main[,3:5], df.combination[1,]),] 
    id date  food1 food2 food3
3 1236  4/1 Orange Juice Apple
> subset(df.main, match_filter(df.main[,3:5], df.combination[1,])) 
    id date  food1 food2 food3
3 1236  4/1 Orange Juice Apple
```

As you can see, since in this case you're interested in columns `3:5` in the `df.main` dataframe, we just pass those to the `match_filter` function.

**Update:**

If you'd like to use a function that can take any number of combinations, then we need to update `match_filter` to accommodate that. The update is really simple and follows the same logic we've seen before:

```
match_filter <- function(df, match_to) {
    apply(df,
          1,
          function(row1) {
              any(apply(match_to,
                    1,
                    function(row2) {
                        !any(is.na(match(row2, row1)))
                    }))
          })
}
```

Now the `match_filter` function is a more generic function that can take any number of combinations and check if `row1` has any of those combinations. And `match_to` in this case can be a dataframe, corresponding to `df.combination`. Here are a few examples using the new function:

First, I added this hypothetical record for illustration purposes:

```
df.main[5,] <- c("1238",   "4/3",     "Apple",    "Avocado", "Orange" )
```

Here are the examples of how the function may be used:

```
# Example showing how the function 
# works with only the first row of df.combination
> df.main[ match_filter(df.main[,3:5], df.combination[1,]),] 
    id date  food1   food2  food3
3 1236  4/1 Orange   Juice  Apple
5 1238  4/3  Apple Avocado Orange
# The first 2 rows of df.combination 
> df.main[ match_filter(df.main[,3:5], df.combination[1:2,]),] 
    id date  food1   food2  food3
2 1235 3/30  Apple    Pear   Meat
3 1236  4/1 Orange   Juice  Apple
5 1238  4/3  Apple Avocado Orange
# All the rows in the df.combination dataframe
> df.main[ match_filter(df.main[,3:5], df.combination),] 
    id date  food1   food2   food3
1 1234 3/29   Sala    Pear Avocado
2 1235 3/30  Apple    Pear    Meat
3 1236  4/1 Orange   Juice   Apple
4 1237  4/2   Pear Avocado  Turkey
5 1238  4/3  Apple Avocado  Orange
```

Comment: Hi @szabad, I think when there's just one row that contains the two desired "foods", it works. But when there are multiple rows, with similar combinations, it doesn't work. My df.main is much bigger, and there are many id's with same combination of foods. Any chance we can modify this? I'd actually rather this function than grep.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to keep any record in `df.main` that has any of the combinations in `df.combination`?

Comment: Right. for example, id 1245 might also have the "Orange" "Juice" "Apple" combination.

Comment: Hey @szabad, thanks for this. I'm getting an error "
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default", literally copying and pasting the code. Is this right?

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird. Please take a look at the whole segment of code on RFiddle and try to run it on your system: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=atWEVp06. If that works for you, then perhaps your dataset is structured somewhat differently and we need to improvise to make it work.